# Why Paxos is required for leader election in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, paxos, leader, gossip

I was reading about the *Protocol for distributed consensus* and came across the [Paxos](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2016/12/paxos-simple-Copy.pdf). It states that you require Paxos for the leader election. [Article](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/consensus-on-cassandra) claiming the same. So, my question is when Cassandra is a ring architecture not master-slave why does it need a leader election mechanism. Moreover, if the answer is yes what is the role of leader in the Cassandra ring. When Gossip protocol is used for communication in the ring.

Comment: It is describing how we can make use of Cassandra for leader election (avoiding zoo keeper). The example demonstrated uses a LWT which internally makes use of Paxos.

Answer (score 3):

The article demonstrated an example of implementing leader election algorithm using Cassandra's feature called Light weight transaction. Its not about electing a master node for Cassandra.

Answer (score 1):

The leader election system is **only** used for Light weight transactions. Light weight transaction allow the user to get isolation for the price of performance.

Consider the following example:
A system manages money for users. 
Let us say one user wants to insert 100$ into an account.

*Current balance (0$) + new money (100$) = 100$.*

Another user wishes to update the same account. He inserts 20$ into that account.
His calculation happens before the first person insert his money.

*Current balance (0$) + new money (20$) = 20$.*

One would expect that the balance after the two insertions of money would be 120$. However, without the leader election, one write will overwrite the other and you will either be left with 100$ or 20$ depending on which write finishes last.

Leader election allows nodes to synchronize their updates on a single resource to make sure that each calculation is isolated. "I will update the value if it is 0$" The election is done so that one node can coordinate the transaction for a particular request.

In our example, the 100$ will be updated but the 20$ will fail and the user will need to try again.

Keep in mind that this leader architecture is distinctly different from master/slave architecture. There is no single point of failure in this as the leader could be any node for a particular request.

More on this topic you can find [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlLtwtTransactions.html).